# display the selected value of a combobox as text

Tags: php, html

Can I display the selected value of a combobox on the same page as text that updates as the selection changes?
I'm trying to build a sentence using combo boxes and input fields.
The combobox represents a name for instance and needs to update in the sentence as it is changed.
I would appreciate any help I can get

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a [server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) language. You will need to use JavaScript to do this client-side if you do not wish to reload the page.

Check out [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) for how to do this with JavaScript.